# Descriptive data with mice/miceadds

Tags: r, imputation, r-mice

I have used mice/miceadds to carry out multiple imputation. I am interested in getting a number of descriptive stats on a "pooled dataset"

Question:
1) I want to know the % of values that are above a specific value in the imputed variable. For example, how many cases have values above 5 (on a scale of 0-10), when all of the imputed datasets are aggregated. Is this feasible with MI data?

2) If #1 is not possible, is there a close alternative?

Comment: Hello, i think it would be helpful to describe what aggregated means. Mice will create m parallel datasets with imputed values. You could now do you're analyses on each of the generated sets and afterwards pool the results or you could aggregate the values after imputation (by calcing the mean or median or mod over all generated sets) and do the desired analysis on the aggregated set. Approach 1 has the benefit, that you get some additional information about the variability over the different imputated sets. Option 2 might be easier to do and needs less computational power.

Comment: I'm interested in option 2-generate as much "pooled" descriptive data as possible and get a sense of the proportion of cases that fall below or above a certain value. Is there a way to get the "pooled" median or mode (and other related descriptives) using miceadds?

Answer (score 1):

Another simple way would be to create a 'long format' complete dataset and simply compute the mean, median or proportion over all imputed datasets. Since Rubin's rules state that your best estimate is the average over all imputations this should give you an appropriate outcome. The only downside is that you will not get an estimate of the standard error of these statistics.

```
impL <- complete(imp,"long",include = F) # long format without the original dataset
mean(impL$x) # Mean of variable x over all datasets
sum(impL$y > 5)/length(impL$y) # proportion of variable y higher than 1 over all datasets
```

Note that if you want an estimate of the frequency (i.e. number of cases) instead of a proportion you will need to divide by the number of imputed datasets (e.g. 5)

```
sum(impL$y > 5)/5
```

Answer (score 0):

What you probably did is something similar to this:

```
# create imputed datasets
imp <- mice(nhanes, m = 5)
#perform lm on all imputed datasets
fit <- with(data = imp, exp = lm(bmi ~ hyp + chl))
#pool results
summary(pool(fit))
```

So you have your pooled results of the lm model.
I guess yo want to know, how did the imputed data look like, that went into the model.

The imputed data actually is in the 'imp' variable.
With imp$imp you would get the values that were imputed for each m. 
Then you can perform the analysis you need on them.

If you need completed data sets (and not only the imputed values) then you would perform

```
complete(imp, action ="all")
```

or if you only want a specific completed dataset m:

```
complete(imp, action =2)
```

E.g. you could then type

```
summary(complete(imp, action =2))
```

to get some summary statistics about the second imputed dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Niek's answer I would do:

```
impL <- complete(imp,"long")
library(stargazer)
stargazer(impL)
```

There you get the mean, standard deviation (Across all the datasets), min and max. I am not completely sure how to calculate the std. dev. properly.

Answer (score 0):

1. Aggregating multiply imputed *datasets* is never feasible.
2. Instead, the estimates (e.g. regression coefficients) are to be aggregated. In your case, the estimand of interest is a proportion, which may be averaged across imputations or reported for each imputation separately.

To compute a proportion for each imputation, see the reprex below. To aggregate over these estimates, use a simple `mean()` call on the `prop` column.

```r
# setup env
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(mice, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
# impute missing data
imp <- mice(nhanes, print = FALSE)
# return completed data
# split by imputation
# and compute proportion of rows where BMI exceeds 25
complete(imp, "long") %>% 
    group_by(.imp) %>% 
    summarize(
        prop = mean(bmi > 25)
    )
#> # A tibble: 5 × 2
#>    .imp  prop
#>   <int> <dbl>
#> 1     1  0.6 
#> 2     2  0.68
#> 3     3  0.72
#> 4     4  0.64
#> 5     5  0.56
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>